# Add Web Service Reference Weird Problem in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, web-reference

I have a WP7 project in VS2010 pro/ultimate and I have added a web reference from another project on the same solution. The web service project is just a normal website project, I just created .ASMX file. I tested the service using web browser and it works fine.

The problem is, after I added this service as service reference, I cannot reference it in my WP7 project and I can't view it in Object Browser either as if it doesn't exist.

I use local URL like 'http://localhost:12345/WebService.asmx' when I added the service, VS can see all the methods and can add successfully. Very strange for me and I don't know how to solve this issue.

Anyone can give me any clue on this? Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the exact same issue myself at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issues before- on one machine, a restart was required, on another, I had to uninstall ALL of my SL stuff, then uninstall Vstudio, then reinstall and reapply any SL add-ons.

Then it worked fine.

Also had a friend with the same issue- uninstall all, then reinstall worked for him also.

I believe these were machines with pre-rtm SL and Phone bits on them.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem.  I created a WP7 project using VB.Net.  I built a WCF Class web service, a client side proxy class, and then a WP7 application with the service reference.  When I added the service reference, the code generating utility would not build the required Reference.svcmap file detail (it only created the header information).  However the project would still compile, yet I couldn't reference the service in code as it didn't exist in the underlying files.

I tried recreating the WP7 project in C# and everything worked.  My guess is that the VB implementation of WP7 might still have some issues, however that is a guess only.  I'm keen to see if anyone else has had the same issue specific to the VB WP7 template or if it is something else.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into the same problem, but it was fixed after a reboot as suggested in this thread by dethSwatch.

I do remember that a silverlight SDK update was installed a bit earlier, maybe the reboot is required after the update?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue might be related to the [January Update to the WP7 tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49b9d0c5-6597-4313-912a-f0cca9c7d277). I managed to fix this issue by installing the VS10-KB2486994-x86.exe fix found on the above page. That sorted the issue I had with generating a client side proxy for the WCF service I wanted to call. Hope this helps.